# Codeigniter validation_errors function is undefined

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Probably there is something I am missing out. I looked around the web and SO for an answer for nothing fixed it for me. Here's my problem: I am loading `form_validation` library in the `__construct` method still PHP complains that `validation_errors` method is undefined. Also `form` helper is autoloaded.

```
...
...
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('ion_auth');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('url');
....
....
function login()
{
    $this->data['title'] = "Login";
    .....
    .....
    //the user is not logging in so display the login page
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
```

Error is thrown on the last line above. (This code is part of ion_auth module http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)

Comment: Did you run the validation already ?

Comment: No. the page errors out on first hit itself.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
$this->data['message'] = ($this->form_validation->run() == False) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
```

Also make sure `helper (form_helper.php)` is loaded before you call the `validation_errors()` helper function because this function is available in this helper file. To load the helper file you may use:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Comment: Hmm.. but I have used this code before and is part of a standard library, thus it looks like a problem with the current configuration. Any hint on that part?

Comment: I'm not sure about `ion_auth` but if the error message says that, `validation_errors()` function is not defined then definitely the helper is not loaded and you may even load this from `config/autoload.php` using `$autoload['helper'] = array('form');` to auto load it in every request.

Comment: Yes, its already added to autoload. Still the function is undefined. Next if I comment out the error line I get an error for `form_open()`

Comment: Out of my knowledge, why `form_open` error should occur ? The `form_open` is also a part of `form` helper and if the helper is already loaded then it doesn't make any sense for the error.

Comment: Point. I have been using Codeigniter for years now, never seen such a thing before.

Comment: So did I (almost 5 years) and now migrated to [Laravel](http://laravel.com), you should try this, you'll love it.

Answer (score 0):

You should call run() method of form_validation class. Also you should define form variables.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
```